# Why I can delete property of global object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'am novice in JS. While reading the book, I found that some examples do not work in firebug or maybe I simply don't understand something.

For example:

```
>>> var a = 1;
undefined
>>> a
1
>>> this.a
1
>>> delete a
true
>>> a;
ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

Why I can delete property of a global object? I read that such variables are nonconfigurable and cannot be deleted.

Maybe that is not important, but it will be better if i understand what is going on:)

Comment: See this article for a comprehensive explanation of the `delete` operator, and an explanation of why you see this behaviour in Firebug: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: No problem :) That's the article that cleared up the `delete` operator for me too.

Comment: @JamesAllardice - you should write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @JamesAllardice:

See this article for a comprehensive explanation of the delete operator, and an explanation of why you see this behaviour in Firebug: [perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete)